# ag-grid: Data Models for .net/c#

Tags: .net, model, ag-grid-angular

I'm starting to implement ag-grid into my angular application with .net core backend.

Unfortunately, I was only able to find Java implementations of their server-side data structures. Before I start converting them to C#/.net I would kindly ask, if there is any implementation of the data models available?

Java implementation can for example found under [1](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-server-side-oracle-example/tree/master/src/main/java/com/ag/grid/enterprise/oracle/demo)

Thank in advance for your hints.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I have a React UI which I'm automated testing with SpecFlow Selenium WebDriver (C#). Some of the pages have ag-grid and i'm trying to think of the best way to interrogate them.

Comment: no, basically did all on my own - but limited to our "needs".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52390314/server-side-filtering-with-angular-6-ag-grid-and-asp-net-and-ef-core-2-1